# How do I determine between a page calling a dynamic javascript file and a user in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm making use of dynamic JavaScript files that are generated in asp.net and then embedded as a normal javascript in an html page. Is there a way for me to determine if the dynamic javascript was opened directly or via the embedded script in the html page?

```
<script src="http://localhost:60919/js.ashx" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to make this determination on the client side, or on the server side?

Comment: on the server side would be best.

Comment: Why do you need to detect this?

Comment: I want to trigger an action based on the call type.

Comment: Could you utilize a hidden field that is only set by either the embedded or dynamic code? Then you could wire up an "onChange" event listener to it and key off of that.

Answer (score 0):

If this was called from the web page, you should see the loading page listed in the referer property.

```
context.Request.UrlReferrer
```

OR

```
context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

This *should* be null if loaded directly by the user. However, a spammer/hacker can manually set the referer to gain access to the script independently of your page.

UPDATED: Handler.ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        context.Response.Write("alert('"+context.Request.UrlReferrer+"');\n");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script src="Handler.ashx"></script>
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Alert shows http://localhost:port/Default.aspx when loaded by the web page. When accessed directly, alert('').

Comment: When is it null? Always or only when called directly? You may need to use context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] instead.

Comment: It seems to always return null. This is what i tried:

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string referer = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
}

Comment: That seems to work, but only when called from an aspx page, but when I call it from an html page it still just shows null.

Comment: You can use Chrome's debugger to verify if the referrer is getting set for content loaded from the web page. If it is there, it should show up in the request variables.

Comment: It just stays blank in HTML page, but works in ASPX page, but I need to get it working in HTML. Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you examine the resource panel of the javascript file in your browser? Is the referrer set in the request headers?